# Get page_impressions from Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), I am trying to obtain the **page_impressions** metric (as described in the [Facebook API Insights Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#page_impressions)) for one of my pages. The actual value that I am looking for is the "Weekly Total Reach" number, found on the Facebook Insights page (https://www.facebook.com/userID?sk=page_insights).

---

### What I've tried under Graph API:

- userID/insights/ - Gives some good info, but nothing about
  page_impressions

### What I've tried under FQL Query:

- SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=userID
  AND metric='page_impressions' AND
  end_time=end_time_date('2012-12-26') AND period=period('week') - This
  returns an empty data set.

---

This same question (or very similar) has been asked a few times on stackoverflow, but I could not find an answer.

Comment: To get page insights, your page should have at least 30 fans.

Comment: Do you mean "Likes"? This particular page has 391. And pulling the insights is working just fine. It is page_impressions that I am trying to pull. It should be the same result as the "Weekly Total Reach". The Insights call is not giving me this. Is there a different call that I need to make to get the "Weekly Total Reach"?

Comment: Oh, I've been blame. You should specify *pageId*, but not *userId*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was really just having issues with my Auth Token. When I used the following Graph API call it worked just fine:

**/[pageId]/insights** (thanks to Oleg, for the correction on pageId)

This gave me all the info I needed, including the page_impressions. And if I wanted just the page_impressions data:

**/[pageId]/insights/page_impressions**